# Storing HTML code in a variable while concatenating MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have a block of code I want to store in a variable so I could make it into a PDF using dompdf

```
$html = '<div class="receiptContainer">
        <center>
            <img src="Images/logo.png" width="175px">
            <h4>GOKUJOU JAPANESE RESTAURANT</h4>
            <p>Total Gas Station, Hibbard Ave., Looc,<br>Dumaguete City, 6200 Negros Oriental, Philippines <br>
            09985555175 | 422-1435 <br>
            <?php echo date("Y-m-d h:i:sA"); ?>
            </p>

            <table width="90%" style="text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>PRICE</th>
                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customerID = '".$_SESSION['customer']."' AND status = '"Checked Out"'");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[5]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[6]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                    $total = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(total) AS grandTotal FROM orders WHERE customerID = '".$_SESSION['customer']."' AND status = '"Checked Out"' GROUP BY customerID");
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($total);
                    $sum = $row[0];
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <!-- break space -->
                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr>

                    <td colspan="1" style="text-align: left">GRAND TOTAL: <?php echo $sum; ?></td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="text-align: left">
                    <td colspan="1">CASH: <?php echo $_SESSION['"cash"']; ?></td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="text-align: left">
                    <td colspan="1">CHANGE: <?php echo $_SESSION['"cash"'] - $sum; ?></td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </div>';
//start PDF generation
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHTML($html);
$dompdf->setPaper(array(0, 0, 1080, 500), 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("samplepdf");
?>
```

This how I structured my code, and it returns me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Gokujou\checkout.php on line 107

and this is line 107:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customerID = '".$_SESSION['customer']."' AND status = '"Checked Out"'");
```

How do I concatenate this MySQL statement properly?

Comment: Can I suggest you to use some IDE? Because there are errors in your code when you're asserting data

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to have a concatenation operator in php if you are using ", only when using '. You can then transform your assignment like this :

`$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customerID = '$_SESSION['customer']' AND status = 'Checked Out'");`

But we can transform what you did into this (to fix with the operator)

`$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customerID = '".$_SESSION['customer']."' AND status = 'Checked Out'");`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error in line 107 is caused because you open the string with " but also have unescaped quotes around "Checked Out"

To escape the quotes, but a backslash before them. i.e.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customerID = '".$_SESSION['customer']."' AND status = '\"Checked Out\"'");
```

The large `$html` section at the top would be better off expressed as a Heredoc. This gives clearer code over multiple lines and removes the need to escape quotes.

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="receiptContainer">
    <center>
    ...
HTML;
```

Finally, you are using the session variable directly in the MySQL query without any kind of sanitization. This could lead to SQL injection attacks if you're not careful.